# How to implement image to part mapping and part selection on click

Tags: image-processing, html5-canvas, artificial-intelligence, fabricjs, konvajs

This is probably not the right place to ask such question but I don't know where to get help on this.

I need to implement a system (web portal) where there is an **admin panel** and a **front end**.

The admin creates and publishes an *Assembly* (An Assembly is a collection of *Parts*). Suppose there is an Assembly 'A1' with Parts 'P1', 'P2' and 'P3'. So the Admin first creates the 3 parts. Then the admin creates the Assembly and adds Parts to it. At the time of creation of Assembly, admin also uploads an image for the Assembly and maps different portions of the image with P1, P2 and P3.

At front end, when the user opens an Assembly's details page, he sees the Assembly's image and a list of Parts which belong to the Assembly. User can check the checkboxes corresponding to the list items to highlighten the Part. This also works the other way round, i.e. User can also click on the Part in Image to check the item in list and highlighten the Part in image.

**My questions is: In Admin Panel, how can I implement Image to Part mapping? i.e. How should the admin select some portion of image and map it to a Part? In what format should the data be saved? (There can be tens of thousands of such Parts and thousands of Assemblies)**

See the images below to understand how the front end user sees and interacts with the application:

**When no Part is checked:**
[image: When no Part is checked]

**When one Part is selected from list:**
[image: When one Part is selected]

**When 2 Parts are selected from list:**
[image: When 2 Parts are selected]

**When user clicks on the left arm:**
[image: When user clicks on the left arm]

Comment: Quite a broad question which I feel is driven more from the DB storage & retrieval side. I would read up on bill-of-material / BOM structures. You will end up with a reference table for the individual parts, then a tree of BOM data for each assembly which lists the parts, their image locations and z-order on the diagram. Drawing the diagram with this data will be easy.